# Python, how can I change value of a variable in the parent scope?

Tags: python, scope, global, python-nonlocal

for example:
assginment statement will declare a new local variable.

```
foo = 'global'
def func1():
    foo = 'func1'
    def func2():
        foo = 'local variable in func2'
```

use global declaration will use the foo in global:

```
def func2():
    global foo
    foo = 'global changed in func2'  #changed the foo value in global scope
```

how can I change the variable foo in func1 scope?
Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

Thank you Brandon Craig Rhodes, I finally understand your meaning.

if there are more than 3 scopes nested, I can store the variable in a list.

```
foo = ['global', 'function1', 'function2']
def func1():
    foo[1] = 'func1'
    def func2():
        foo[2] = 'func2'
        foo[1] = 'func1 modified in func2'
```

I just use a global variable actually.

---

so, if there are two functions nested, we can use

```
nonlocal foo
```

and

```
global foo
```

if there are more than three functions nested, 
and each function use variables in other functions scope,
 why don't we declare a global list variable?
**Thank you for all your help!!!**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Python 3, I believe, you can use the `nonlocal` keyword to get permission to modify a variable in an enclosing non-global scope.  In Python 2, you cannot reassign `foo` in an enclosing scope; instead, set `foo` equal to a mutable object like a list `[]` and then stick the value you want stored in the list:

```
def func1():
    foo = [None]
    def func2():
        foo[0] = 'Test'
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. but just in imagination, how about if there are more than 3 functions nested?Would you please help more?thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I finally understand what was your meaning. if there are more than two functions nested, you can use foo[1, 2, 3] to store every value in foo[0] foo[1] foo[2] element. Thank you again!

Answer (score 9):

In python 3.0 and above you can use the nonlocal keyword.